# BeautifulSoup, TypeError:'NoneType' object is not callable. from book: Web Scraping With Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

This train from a book, Python Web Scraping With Python by Ryan Mitchell,in Chinese version p23.and I find any others are similar.who can tell me how fix it? thank you in advance.
I has posted picture. code as follow:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
images = bsObj.findALL("img",{"src":re.compile("\.\.\/img\/gifts\/img.*\.jpg")})
for image in images:
    print(image["src"])
```

Comment: Post your code *here*, as text.

Comment: The weekly "I'm trying to parse HTML with regex" question.

Comment: Now, update the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually the `*findALL*` it should be lowercase *l's* i.e `findAll` or better to use `*find_all*` as *findAll* is deprecated.:

```
 images = bsObj.find_all("img",{"src":re.compile("\.\./img/gifts/img.*\.jpg")})
```

Which will give you:

```
../img/gifts/img1.jpg
../img/gifts/img2.jpg
../img/gifts/img3.jpg
../img/gifts/img4.jpg
../img/gifts/img6.jpg
```

Unless there were other images with `../img/gifts/img` in their path you could use  a *css selector* in place of the regex to find images that had
*/img/gifts/img* in their *src* attribute.

```
images = bsObj.select("img[src*=../img/gifts/img]")
```